# AJAX returns null value on success call

Tags: jquery

I have a small problem with jQuery `$.ajax()` function. I am trying to post the JSON data to the server but on success call I get `null` data. Please find the code below:

```
function uploadretdata(retinvoiceval) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: wsurl + "js/validation",
        cache: false,
        timeout: 20000,
        data: {
            retinvoiceval: retinvoiceval
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("data : " + data); // returns null data
        },
        error: function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: If the `success` handler is being hit, then the AJAX request is working fine. This means that the endpoint you call is returning nothing. You need to check the server code and debug any issues there as the JS code is not the problem.

Comment: Thanks Rory for your comments .When I debug i found the data is empty which means data sent from ajax is null.

Comment: I also tried to send using postman but same null data

Comment: Exactly - the problem is in the code that your `wsurl + "js/validation"` URL points to. The JS is fine.

Comment: and what actually is it? `wsurl`

Comment: Returning null can be a valid response - the relevant part is the response "Status" code (easily seen in Postman) - it will only hit `success:` if it's a `200`.